# How to let Vim show a list of alternative file paths of the same basic name when use gf?

Tags: vim, goto

I know, in **Vim**, `gf` leads me to the file (actually the first one) whose name is under or after the cursor, ***n*** `gf` leads to the ***n*** th file with the same basic name.

I wonder how I can let Vim show a list of all alternatives(if there are), just like `g<C-]>` to give a list of those for a symbol under the cursor, so I can select the one I'm interested in.

Generally speaking, I need this feature to jump to a c header file that I care.

e.g.

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string.h
/usr/include/string.h       -- I care this
/usr/include/linux/string.h
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [Smartgf](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4386)?  From the page:

> It's better than default gf because:
>
> - It doesn't use ctags. So you don't need to run anything after changes.
> - **It shows you all available matches.**
>
> ...
>
> Use 1-9 keys as quick shortcuts to select search result or use j,k to change cursor 
>   position in the dialog and o,Enter to choose selected item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I don't think this gives what I need. The list shows many entries of files in which the header file is referred to, not the alternative header files with the same name under the cursor.